# Is there a way to make Visual Studio for Mac OS recognise the case of a filename?

Tags: visual-studio-mac

In VS on Mac OS when I try to rename a file then if the file exists with a different case it won't let me rename it.  Is there any way around this.  Seems like something I would have thought would have been fixed 20 years ago :-(

[image]

[image]

Comment: By default, the macOS file system is case insensitive, meaning that GsButton.xaml and GSButton.xaml are really just different ways of writing the same filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure I understand your issue, are you trying to rename a file to a name that's already exist (with or without the same case)? because if that's the case, you won't be able since apfs isn't case sensitive as far as I know.

Comment: I am trying to rename a file from GssButton to GsButton.  However I file with name GSButton exists and it appears Mac OS visual studio does not handle case sensitivity of filenames :-(

Comment: As I was saying, APFS isn't case sensitive (unless you set it to be), so if there's a file exist already with the name you desire, you cannot create / rename another file to its name in the same directory no matter the case. you'll have to use a different name or save it under a different directory with the name you want.